# MVC and Sub or Sub Sub Folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to migrate an Asp Intranet.

But, when i look for create an MVC Intranet, i realise that i can't do that :

For Example, in the Area "Folder 1"

/Folder1/Home (In Real : /Folder1/Controller/HomeController.vb)
/Folder1/Application/Agency/Home (In Real : /Folder1/Controller/Agency/HomeController.vb)
/Folder1/Application/Agency/Edition/MyAppEdition/Home (In Real : /Folder1/Controller/Agency/Edition/MyAppEdition/HomeController.vb)

is it possible to do that? Or in MVC, it's not recommanded and i have to create only to Sub Folder like "/Folder1/View/MyApp" ?

Thank'

Portekoi

Answer (score 1):

In MVC your URLS do not map to file or folder locations.

They are controlled by the specified [routes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You'd need to setup your routes to get the URLs you want.

Comment: Ok, i saw that but can i have multiple route for one area like my example?

Comment: You have two with "Home" in the URL, this is certainly possible with routing.